# Adding static routes to debian 10 in /network/interfaces

Tags: debian, networking, route

I used to add static routes up until debian 9 this way:

```
up route add -net 1.2.3.4.5/23 gw 2.3.4.5.6
up route add -host 2.3.4.5 gw 3.4.5.6
```

What changed for debian10 and what's the new syntax for static routes in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `up ...` lines are not stand-alone, but they are extensions of an `iface ...` line before them. Before Debian 9, the actual network interface used to pretty much always be the last entry in `/etc/network/interfaces`, so just adding `up route add ...`  lines at the end might have actually worked pretty often.

If you chose to install a desktop environment, the installation is likely to include NetworkManager, and in that case, there may be no `iface` line for your network interface at all, allowing the interface to be controlled by NetworkManager instead. In that case, you could use one-time `nmcli` commands to persistently add new routes:

```
 nmcli c modify eno1 +ipv4.routes "1.2.3.4/23 2.3.4.5" # network route
 nmcli c modify eno1 +ipv4.routes "2.3.4.5 3.4.5.6" # host route
```

And if you don't use NetworkManager... the `net-tools` package that includes the old `ifconfig` and `route` commands has been deprecated since Debian 9, and is no longer installed by default. So unless you have explicitly chosen to install `net-tools`, you should use the newer `ip route` commands instead:

```
iface eno1 ...
    up /bin/ip route add 1.2.3.4/23 via 2.3.4.5   # network route
    up /bin/ip route add 2.3.4.5/32 via 3.4.5.6   # single host route
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, any idea why the routes don't apply after a reboot?

Comment: Are you sure you have not made any typos, e.g. specified a gateway IP that is not reachable directly with the IP/netmask configuration of that interface? Are you using NetworkManager or not, and if not, have you made sure NetworkManager is definitely disabled? In `/etc/network/interfaces`, you may need to use an absolute path: `up /bin/ip ...` instead of just `up ip ...`.

Comment: using `nmcli` you might want to use `nmcli connection show` to get your value of eno1 above.

Comment: A bit late to the party, but did you find a solution? I found that when using `dhcp` the `up` command is not executed.

Answer (score 4):

This works for debian 9 (debian stretch), debian 10 (debian buster) and debian 11 (debian bullseye):

Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` file and add your permanent routes.

Example:

```
auto ens192
allow-hotplug ens192
iface ens192 inet static
    address 192.168.221.54/24
    gateway 192.168.221.1
    dns-nameservers 82.99.137.41 212.158.133.41
    dns-search secar.cz
    up ip route del 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.221.1 dev ens192 
    up ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.221.1 dev ens192
    up ip route del 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.221.1 dev ens192
    up ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.221.1 dev ens192
```

Here is [completed guide for permanent debian static routes](https://www.mybluelinux.com/debian-permanent-static-routes/)

Comment: I could not find the `route` command on my Debian 11, I wonder, has it been moved to be a function of `ip` now?

Comment: I don't use the route command anywhere in my tutorial...

Comment: In the example above there's `ip route add`. This used to be done with the `route` command by itself. Now I see it has been integrated as a function of `ip`

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem in `/etc/systemd/network/`, here i put all network configuration!

Replace or comment if exists: `dhcp.network` file for static.network

```
[Match]
Name=e*

[Network]
Address=aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa/aa  (MY IP)
Gateway=ccc.ccc.ccc.ccc         (Default Gateway)
DNS= 8.8.8.8
DNS= 8.8.4.4


[Route]
Destination=yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy/yy
GatewayOnlink=true
Gateway=zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz
Metric=1


[Route]
Destination=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx
GatewayOnlink=true
Gateway=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Metric=1
```